# Renamed folder in workspace android - all files 0 bytes

Tags: android, eclipse, directory, workspace

I've been working on an android app and recently did something pretty dumb...

I renamed a folder in my workspace.  When I opened the workspace again, all my files were 0 bytes.  The files are there but the data is gone.

Is there a way to get my data back?  None of it was backed up...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to close the workspace, restart eclipse and open the workspace again. I hope it works.. else I feel sorry for your loss.